# Laravel 5.4 não tem Middleware/Authenticate.php

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, middleware

estou seguindo um exemplo sobre jwt e Laravel 5 e estou precisando do arquivo Middleware/Authenticate.php, porem, no meu projeto, não existe o arquivo(versão do Laravel é 5.4.36), tentei o comando **php artisan make:auth** mas ele não gerou o arquivo.
Como posso fazer para ele criar o Middleware/Authenticate.php ?

Comment: Você entra na pasta Middlwware e cria o arquivo manualmente. Depois você volta para o seu tutorial e colocar dentro dele o conteudo necessario.

Answer (score 0):

Pesquisando um pouco mais sobre middleware no Laravel, encontrei o comando para criar um middleware que é **php artisan make:middleware Authenticate**, porem, esse comando cria o arquivo apenas com a função handle() pois ele não sabe a implementação(rsrsrsr), para minha sorte eu tinha uma implementação de um outro sistema que vou deixar aqui o fonte como exemplo caso mais alguém precise (modifique caso necessário!).

**Middleware/Authenticate.php:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;

class Authenticate
{

    /**
    * The Guard implementation.
    *
    * @var Guard
    */
   protected $auth;

   /**
    * Create a new filter instance.
    *
    * @param  Guard  $auth
    * @return void
    */
   public function __construct(Guard $auth)
   {
           $this->auth = $auth;
   }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($this->auth->guest())
        {
                if ($request->ajax())
                {
                        return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
                }
                else
                {
                        return redirect()->guest('auth/login');
                }
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```